# Binding multiple ComboBoxes to the same collection but filtering just one

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a custom control, SearchableComboBox, which inherits from ComboBox.  It simply has a textbox above the items control which filters the visible items, currently by setting the Items.Filter.

There are multiple SearchableComboBoxes on my form all bound to the same collection.  I want them to be independently searchable, however with the way I have things wired right now, if I filter one then they all get filtered (and if one has a selection already which doesn't match the filter, its selection gets cleared).

I've also tried adding an UnfilteredItems property to the SearchableComboBox, binding to that and then using a CollectionView created from the UnfilteredItems as the ItemsSource, then doing the filtering via the CollectionView.  This gives the exact same functionality, where all the SearchableComboBoxes are being filtered together.

Any help with this is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Show how you are filtering.  Show how you are binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be using `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView()` associated with your `ItemsSource` which will always return same instance of `ICollectionView` related to your source collection.

Instead **create new `CollectionViewSource` and bind with its `View` property which will be unique for your binding.**

Something like this:

```
private ICollectionView customView;
public ICollectionView CustomView
{
   get
   {
      if (customView== null)
      {
         customView= new CollectionViewSource()
                     { Source = SourceCollection }.View;
         customView.Filter = p => !(p as CustomClass).BoolProperty;
      }
      return customView;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response, I figured it out just after posting!  I will mark yours as the correct answer once I'm allowed to do so.

Comment: Yeah after reading your question that's the first thing that crossed my mind.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Aaaaand of course 2 minutes after posting the question I've been banging my head against for over an hour, I figured it out myself.

I was creating the CollectionView by calling CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView on the source collection, which seems to be returning the same reference for all the SearchableComboBoxes.  If I instead instantiate a new CollectionViewSource, set it's Source property to the source collection, then set my ItemsSource to the CollectionViewSource.View property, this now works as I want and each SearchableComboBox filters independently of the others.